# struts2 with tiles2 and thymeleaf

Tags: struts2, tiles2, thymeleaf

Does anybody know how to integrate struts2, tiles2 and thymeleaf?

I can do the following integrations:

- struts2, tiles2, freemarker
- spring mvc, tiles2, thymeleaf

But for a migration from struts1, tiles1, jsp would be good to have the migration path as stated.

Comment: Bit off topic but what is the benefit of thymeleaf? freemarker and velocity are quite mature and have traction and they don't require a web container, either although that is what they are most often used for. Just curious.

Comment: If you want thymeleaf integration I would advise figuring out how to use thymeleaf in a plain servlet environment. That is without struts2 or spring mvc, this will make the setup, dependencies and over all interaction very clear. After you have done this then you will create a custom result (implement com.opensymphony.xwork2.Result). Look in struts.xml to see how result types are registered. It's actually pretty easy to write such a result class and there a number of examples on the web.

Comment: Also I would upgrade to tiles-3 directly the plugin already exists, there is little use difference between tiles-2 and tiles-3, should you just wish to stick with tiles-2 features but should you want tiles-3 features it would be nice that they are available (some of them are quite convenient).

Comment: @Quaternion: Thymeleaf templates look closer to the webstandards than freemarker templates. For the sustainability of the view this is an important point for me.

Comment: Oh sorry... I reread your question and realized the solution would be struts2-thymeleaf integration but you want tiles-thymeleaf integration, because struts2 will hand off view rendering to tiles so it does not need to be aware of working with thymeleaf directly, but I think creating a thymeleaf plugin for struts2 should be pretty easy and at some point you'll want it. Sorry but I have a feeling the tiles integration will be a bit harder. Best to consult the tiles mailing list.

Comment: You'll need to create a custom "org.apache.tiles.request.render", probably not that hard. And somehow register that with tiles (I have the feeling this will be hard). See: http://tiles.apache.org/framework/config-reference.html (Registering Renderers)

Comment: This question talks about integrating Struts2 and Thymeleaf, but doesn't include Tiles. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003058/how-to-integrate-struts2-with-thymeleaf