# How to integrate Struts2 with Thymeleaf?

Tags: struts2, thymeleaf

Does anybody know how to integrate Struts2 with Thymeleaf? I could not find any tutorial regarding integrating Struts2 and Thymeleaf.

Comment: Looks like right now there is no easy way to do that: http://forum.thymeleaf.org/How-to-Integrate-Thymeleaf-with-Jakarta-Struts-td4025795.html

Comment: Also pretty similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16671703/1430055

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a simple plugin that supports using Thymeleaf templates as the result type for Struts2 actions. The readme file contains examples of how to use the plug-in. You'll need to build the plug-in from source, as its not currently in any Maven repositories.

https://github.com/codework/struts2-thymeleaf-plugin